# R: Proper way to put library() in .Rprofile while not causing error when installing package

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I used to put following code in .Rprofile to preload the packages I always use

```
library(tidyverse)
library(...)
...etc
```

However, it costs me errors some time while installing packages. For example:

```
* installing *source* package ‘prada’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c inPolygon.c -o inPolygon.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o prada.so inPolygon.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-prada/00new/prada/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.0 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.3.2     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
✔ tibble  3.0.4     ✔ dplyr   1.0.2
✔ tidyr   1.1.2     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
✔ readr   1.4.0     ✔ forcats 0.5.0

Error: [conflicted] `Position` found in 2 packages.
Either pick the one you want with `::` 
* ggplot2::Position
* base::Position
Or declare a preference with `conflict_prefer()`
* conflict_prefer("Position", "ggplot2")
* conflict_prefer("Position", "base")
...
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘prada’ had non-zero exit status
```

I can successfully install this package after I clean up me .Rprofile, but it is annoying to do it everytime. I'm wondering is there any better way to avoid this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is one of the packages you are loading automatically `conflicted`? Is this error message specific to installing `prada`? How exactly are you installing packages?

Comment: In this specific case, prada is a dependent package which is automatically installed when I'm using BiocManager::install("..."). I don't think it is specific to "prada" tho, since I encounter similar problem before and solved by temporally emptying my .Rprofile